# problem with console(ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

**when i  write a js code and run it in the console.. it runs but below of that 3 error came that are all same... and that error is:**

`DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://nndknepjnldbdbepjfgmncbggmopgden/map/js/dm_content.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

*and for a quick note i have seen some similar issues but they aren't exactly same as with mine so plz see it twice...*

Comment: The error tells you exactly what's happening: there is a Chrome extension and the JS map file cannot be found. If you run your JS in FireFox do you get the same error? This appears not be an issue with your code, but with the Chrome extension.

Comment: i would be helpful if you provide more insight to what you were running on console. On the other hand, I also feel like this is related to a extension running on your browser. Try a different browser or chrome incognito mode or a online javascript editor like jsfiddle if possible to see if that does the same..

Comment: i just wrote simple line like  `console.log('ABCDEF');`
and i use vscode and added a extension in vs code named live server to see my results in the browser...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not an error with OPs code. It's caused by a browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

In `dm_content.js` something is requesting a url scheme that is not known.
A url scheme is like `http://` `https://`  `ftp://`  etc.

Find out what it tries to access and you got your answer.

edit:
the extension that causes the error is the data scraper extension.
at some point of the scraping it runs into an invalid url for that context.
This could be a `mailto://` link in an iframe or any scheme that is invalid for the context it is scraping

Comment: I edited the answer, hope it helps.. in any case it has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: i just wrote simple line like `console.log('ABCDEF');` and i use vscode and added a extension in vs code named live server to see my results in the browser... after that i got that error...can u tell that what exactly i should do?? do i remove data scraper (*which is not a great choice*)

Comment: just ignore it, the data scraper can not scrape your code... most likely it is looking for a url in your `console.log` which it will never find. if you don't want to see the error at all, you can temporarily disable the scraper while working on your code.

Comment: oh means to temporarily off data scraper during my tests and then turning it off.. Thanks buddy!

Comment: @thanostheherowins if the answer solved your problem, please accept it as so.